# How to rename file in BLOB container

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Can you please let me know if it is a possible to rename a file in a BLOB container using SDK. In most of the suggestion it is recommended to create a new BLOB, copy the content of the old BLOB & then delete the old BLOB. However, due to size of the files I do not seem it will be an ideal solution in the architecture that I am working with. So I am searching for an alternate way of achieving result.

Kind Regards,

Comment: The advice you've received is the best advice, as it's the only way to "rename" a blob (copy to new blob). Curious about your concerns with performance & size: have you benchmarked a copy operation? Given that the copy takes place within Azure Storage itself (no need to download somewhere then re-upload), this should be a fairly efficient operation.

Comment: @FrankGong - when I posted the comment, I really didn't feel this question needed a formal answer, as it's a fairly well documented thing (which is why I replied the way I did, vs posting an answer) - effectively a yes/no answer. The rest of it is fairly broad in nature, and makes assertions about performance of copying (which the OP still hasn't provided any further detail on when I challenged the performance assertion and asked about benchmarking).

Comment: Plus, you're asking the OP to accept an answer that 1) I posted originally as a comment and 2) is essentially telling the OP what they already knew but were hoping to find an alternative, which there is none.